# Where can I get watsonPI api documentation?

Tags: personality-insights, watson-personality-insights

I was searching for API documentaion for Watson PI and came across https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/personality-insights#service-endpoint from the [main page](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/personality-insights?topic=personality-insights-release-notes) which leads to no where as the page is not available.

Any idea where can I  get the documentation for the same?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the service is being deprecated and maybe this is the reason why you cannot find anything relevant. They mention to consider Watson NLU instead.
https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/personality-insights?topic=personality-insights-overviewDevelopers